# No SecurityTokenValidator available for token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3

I created an `IdentityServer` and can successfully retrieve a token by passing the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` to the token endpoint

My IndetityServer setup is below

```
var certFile = env.ApplicationBasePath + $"{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}idsrv3test.pfx";

var options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
        .UseInMemoryClients(Client.Get())
        .UseInMemoryScopes(Scope.Get())
        .UseInMemoryUsers(User.Get()),
            SigningCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "idsrv3test"),
            RequireSsl = false
};

app.UseIdentityServer(options);
```

When I make a call to my protected MVC 6 Web API, I get a

> No SecurityTokenValidator available for token:
>   c7f2c3890d83a454fcb504cb96c75fe7

Here is the setup in the `Startup.cs` of my API

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = $@"{tokenServiceUrl}";
    options.Audience = $@"{tokenServiceUrl}/resources";
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```

I made sure that this setup is done before the `app.UseMvc()` call. Is there anything else that I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

> Install-Package
>   IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.Integration.AspNet -Pre

from the package manager console to install the integration package for your API. Then add the folloing code to the Configure method for the Startup.cs class of the API

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication
(
    new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = tokenServiceUrl,
        ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "SomeScope" }
    }
);
```